# Blank Fields vs NULL - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I apologize in advance for this being confusing but....

I have a large number of rows that need to be inserted into a SQL SERVER table.

I have created insert statements for each using Excel then just copy/paste it into sql server and add it to the table.

The problem is that I need at least have 9 available "Key" fields as you'll see below, (eg Key1, Key2, etc.) but not every row has data for the 9 fields and those appear blank(see below)

Below is an example of an insert statement along with what a picture of what I'm getting in Sql Server:

```
INSERT INTO ILOOKUP (LISTNAME,VALUE,KEY1,KEY2,KEY3,KEY4,KEY5,KEY6,KEY7,KEY8,KEY9,COMMENT,MODIFIEDBY) VALUES ('ANY_REFVALUE_LIST','1000--100010000X-67141000','1000100008','100010008','1000100000X','','','','','','','ANY_REFVALUE_LIST','ZH')
```

[image]

What I want is for those fields to display as "NULL" instead of being blank.

Comment: So set `null` instead of `""` empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inserting an empty string you need to insert NULL. I would also suggest that your table seems to be in need of some normalization. Anytime you see numbered columns like Key1, Key2 it is sign something is a bit off.

```
INSERT INTO ILLOOKUP 
(
    LISTNAME
    , VALUE
    , KEY1
    , KEY2
    , KEY3
    , KEY4
    , KEY5
    , KEY6
    , KEY7
    , KEY8
    , KEY9
    , COMMENT
    , MODIFIEDBY
) 
VALUES 
(
    'ANY_REFVALUE_LIST'
    , '1000--100010000X-67141000'
    , '1000100008'
    , '100010008'
    , '1000100000X'
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'ANY_REFVALUE_LIST', 'ZH'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `INSERT` statement you need to specify `NULL` instead of blank.

Answer (score 2):

simply use
insert into TableName (columnName ) values(null)